# Control .fadeOut() with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.gallery-slider li:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.gallery-slider li:first-child').fadeOut("slow")
         .next('.gallery-slider li').fadeIn(1000)
         .end().appendTo('.gallery-slider');}, 
      2000);
});
</script>
```

The .fadeIn seems to be working, however the .fadeOut does not seem to be properly accepting the speed parameter. What do I need to change such that it will properly work? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the fade functions don't block..

You can pass a function to fadeout so that it runs after its complete, e.g.

```
$('.blarg').fadeOut(100, function() {
  $('.blarg).fadeIn();
});
```

Would wait until its totally faded out before it tries to fade back in.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I can't seem to get the syntax working. How would properly using the .fadeOut work with the above original code?

Comment: @Joesph is right.  I was having an issue with calling fadeIn after fadeOut - the issue is that fadeOut wasn't setting the element to be totally hidden before the next line of code ran out which briefly caused (in my code) two banners to be shown in a container at the same time.  Thats what led me to believe it was non-blocking - what I had to do instead was just call hide() after the fadeOut to ensure that it occured in order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.gallery-slider li:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
    $('.gallery-slider li:first-child').fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(this).next('.gallery-slider li').fadeIn(1000)
    }).appendTo('.gallery-slider');}, 
    2000);
```

Comment: Tried it. This just rotates between the first two images, rather than displaying all in a cycle.